# Flurry: Session doesn't track on IOS using ionic3

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins, flurry, xcode10.2

> I have flurry-analytics in integrated in ionic3 project although **its
>   working perfectly in android** but **in IOS it doesn't track
>   sessions.**

**Ionic:**

```
   Ionic CLI          : 5.2.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
```

Cordova:

```
   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 6.3.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1, (and 26 other plugins)
```

System:

```
   NodeJS : v10.16.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.10.1
   OS     : macOS Mojave
```

I have used below flurry-analytics plugin :

[https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/flurry-analytics/][1]

and simply initized it.

```
let flurryAnalyticsOptions = {
                            appKey: 'IOSApiKey', // REQUIRED
                            enableCrashReporting: true,
                            reportSessionsOnClose: true,
                            enableLogging: true
                        };
                        flurryAnalyticsObject = this.flurryAnalytics.create(flurryAnalyticsOptions)
```

**Here is what my logs says about flurry when I try to run app.**

```
2019-07-26 10:51:36.715276+0530 [696:192124] Flurry: Starting session on Agent Version [Flurry_iOS_196_8.0.0]

2019-07-26 10:51:36.791643+0530 [696:192124] THREAD WARNING: ['FlurryAnalyticsPlugin'] took '78.294922' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.

=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication statusBarOrientation]
PID: 696, TID: 192988, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.Flurry.Analytics.Session, QoS: 0

Backtrace:
4  0x0000000102d1f734 +[FlurryiOSUtil canvasInLandscapeRight] + 56
5  0x0000000102d1f6d8 +[FlurryiOSUtil canvasInLandscape] + 32
6  0x0000000102d0c6b8 +[FlurryUtil canvasInLandscape] + 44
7  0x0000000102cf9420 -[FlurrySession data] + 2400
8  0x0000000102cf8138 -[FlurrySession sendSessionsToServerIncludingCurrentSession:] + 820
9  0x0000000102cf7de8 -[FlurrySession sendSessionsToServerForCreateSession] + 328
10  0x0000000102ce4898 __50-[FlurryImpl sendSessionsToServerForCreateSession]_block_invoke + 52
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved!
I was trying to pass "userId" param as interger but it should be string type.
This was breaking session start in IOS only.

Hope this will help someone in future.